# Bounding Box with Python

Tags: python, axis

I wish to obtain the Axis-aligned minimum Bounding Box (AABB) coords from a selected object, or from each object of a collection with a python script. Any references are very apreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Conspiques.. this does seem very likely to be a duplicate question. If the linked answers don't work for you, by all means edit to explain why, and we can re-open for you.